Spring WebClient interceptor for SSE events
Is there any known practice for Spring Web app to intercept SSE (server-sent-events) with a filter function (or similar) like it is done for plain old HTTP requests/response:
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("http://localhost:5555")
    .filter(createExchangeFilterFunction())
    .build();

Or the only way to do it is to write own logic based on doOnNext/subscribe calls?
